# Uart iphone 4 augmented reality

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

I am trying to run this project https://research.cc.gatech.edu/uart/content/trackerwrapper on iphone 4. I managed to open the camera but the image is interlaced.Do you know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following thread for much more information on this:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/uart/forums/forum/1087070/topic/4413280

It seems that the problem has to do with sending an image to the screen that has a lower resolution than what the screen is.